# method not allowed 405 when trying to call from angular httpclient to asp.net web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-http

I am trying to create a call from my Angular 4 application to my server that is asp.net web api, first of all I enabled cors in my server and it seems working, now when I am trying to call I am getting method not allowed

WebApi.config:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
    // Web API configuration and services
    // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();



    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Controller method example:

```
        [HttpGet, Route("api/authentication")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string username, string password)
    {
        var s = new ApartmentService();

        if (!s.CheckIfValidLogin(username, password))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

client code:

```
public url = 'http://localhost:50743/api/authentication';

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params.append('username', username);
    params.append('password', password);
    return this.http.get(this.url, {
      params: params,
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'),
    }).map((result: Response) => result.json());
  }
```

i tried also with header content type: application/json and also didn't worked.

error:
[image: error]

its working fine if I did the request with postman...

Thanks.

Comment: `return this.http.get(this.url,...` - the `http` in there, is it `HttpClientModule` or `HttpModule`?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `GET` request to an endpoint that only accepts `POST`, that is the reason for the `Method Not Allowed` error.

Send your request using `POST` instead. I'm not familiar with angular but try something like

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params.append('username', username);
    params.append('password', password);
    return this.http.post(this.url, parems {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'),
    }).map((result: Response) => result.json());
}
```

Refer to the [angular docs for http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)